# Select textfield and bring up keyboard before showing viewcontroller - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have the following code that is sending information to the next `UIViewController`. In the next `UIViewController` I have a `UITextField`. When the function `commentsTapped` is being used (which means it will go to the next `UIViewController`), it should automatically "select" the `UITextField` and bring up the keyboard.

Here is my code:

```
func commentsTapped(cell: updateTableViewCell) {
  let allDataSend = cell.pathDB
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showComments", sender: allDataSend)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "showComments" {
    if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? commentsTableViewController {
      nextVC.dataGotten = sender! as! String
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `commentsTableViewController`'s  `viewDidLoad` method add this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  yourTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This way, you will see the keyboard appear after the view controller is loaded:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: This works better when you want to show the keyboard immediately after pushing a new viewcontroller to the navigation stack. This way the animation is smooth unlike in `viewDidLoad`.